# Opencsv: Allow for a more customized error message when using @PreAssignmentValidator

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

Given this bean:

```
@Data
public class Contact {
    @PreAssignmentValidator(validator = MustMatchRegexExpression.class, paramString = "^[A-Za-z]{3,8}$")
    @CsvBindByName(column = "Contact First Name", required = true)
    private String contactFirstName;

    @PreAssignmentValidator(validator = MustMatchRegexExpression.class, paramString = "^[0-9]{10}$")
    @CsvBindByName(column = "Phone Number", required = true)
    private String phone;
}
```

and the CsvToBeanBuilder() configured as follows:

```
...
final CsvToBean<Contact> beans = new CsvToBeanBuilder<Contact>(
                    Files.newBufferedReader(csvFilePath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                    .withType(Contact.class)
                    .withThrowExceptions(false)
                    .build();

this.contacts = beans.parse();

beans.getCapturedExceptions().stream().forEach(ex -> System.out.println(ex.getMessage()));
...
```

If I give it a file like:

```
Contact First Name,Phone Number
joe1,1234567890
jane,123456789
```

I (correctly) get these error messages:

```
Field userName value "joe1" did not match expected format of ^[A-Za-z]{3,8}$
Field phone value "123456789" did not match expected format of ^[0-9]{10}$
```

Since I am passing these messages back to the user, I would prefer if the error message used the CSV column name instead of the bean's field name, and if I can provide a custom validation message -- maybe as an additional field the @PreAssignmentValidator? -- so that the messages look like:

```
Field 'User Name' value "joe1" did not match expected format of '3 - 8 alphabetic characters'
Field 'Phone Number' value "123456789" did not match expected format of '10 digits'
```

Any suggestions/pointers on how I can do this without writing some custom logic to transform these messages?

Thank you!

---

Code updated based on suggestion from @andrewjames

```
@Getter
public class Contact {
    //@PreAssignmentValidator(validator = MustMatchRegexExpression.class, paramString = "^[A-Za-z]{3,8}$")
    @CsvBindByName(column = "Contact First Name", required = true)
    private String contactFirstName;

    //@PreAssignmentValidator(validator = MustMatchRegexExpression.class, paramString = "^[0-9]{10}$")
    @CsvBindByName(column = "Phone Number", required = true)
    private String phone;

    public void setContactFirstName(String contactFirstName) throws CsvValidationException {
        if (contactFirstName.length() < 3 || contactFirstName.length() > 8) {
            throw new CsvValidationException("'Contact First Name' must be between 3-8 characters long");
        }
        this.contactFirstName = contactFirstName;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) throws CsvValidationException {
        if (phone.length() != 10) {
            throw new CsvValidationException("'Phone Number' must be between 10 digits long");
        }
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}

public class ContactTest {
    private static final String HEADER = "Contact First Name,Phone Number\n";


    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        String data = HEADER
                + "jo,1234567890\n"
                + "al,123456789";  // This row should generate two exceptions

        CsvToBean<Contact> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<Contact>(new StringReader(data))
                .withType(Contact.class)
                .withThrowExceptions(false)
//                .withExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandlerQueue())  // Tried this way after commenting previous line
                .build();

        List<Contact> beans = csvToBean.parse();

        csvToBean.getCapturedExceptions().stream().forEach((ex) -> {
                System.out.println((int) ex.getLineNumber() + " -- " + ex.getMessage());
        });
    }
}
```

But now the csvToBean.parse() just throws the exeptions. And For the second row, I only get the first exception:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-2" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvBeanIntrospectionException: An introspection error was thrown while attempting to manipulate property contactFirstName of bean org.lotia.example.entity.Contact.
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.run(ProcessCsvLine.java:111)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvBeanIntrospectionException: An introspection error was thrown while attempting to manipulate property contactFirstName of bean org.lotia.example.entity.Contact.
    at com.opencsv.bean.AbstractBeanField.assignValueToField(AbstractBeanField.java:290)
    at com.opencsv.bean.AbstractBeanField.setFieldValue(AbstractBeanField.java:182)
    at com.opencsv.bean.AbstractMappingStrategy.setFieldValue(AbstractMappingStrategy.java:607)
    at com.opencsv.bean.AbstractMappingStrategy.populateNewBean(AbstractMappingStrategy.java:330)
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.processLine(ProcessCsvLine.java:131)
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.run(ProcessCsvLine.java:87)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.opencsv.bean.FieldAccess.lambda$determineAssignmentMethod$3(FieldAccess.java:79)
    at com.opencsv.bean.FieldAccess.setField(FieldAccess.java:115)
    at com.opencsv.bean.AbstractBeanField.assignValueToField(AbstractBeanField.java:286)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvValidationException: 'Contact First Name' must be between 3-8 characters long
    at org.lotia.example.entity.Contact.setContactFirstName(Contact.java:23)
    ... 15 more
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvBeanIntrospectionException: An introspection error was thrown while attempting to manipulate property contactFirstName of bean org.lotia.example.entity.Contact.
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.run(ProcessCsvLine.java:111)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvBeanIntrospectionException: An introspection error was thrown while attempting to manipulate property contactFirstName of bean org.lotia.example.entity.Contact.
    at com.opencsv.bean.AbstractBeanField.assignValueToField(AbstractBeanField.java:290)
    at com.opencsv.bean.AbstractBeanField.setFieldValue(AbstractBeanField.java:182)
    at com.opencsv.bean.AbstractMappingStrategy.setFieldValue(AbstractMappingStrategy.java:607)
    at com.opencsv.bean.AbstractMappingStrategy.populateNewBean(AbstractMappingStrategy.java:330)
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.processLine(ProcessCsvLine.java:131)
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.run(ProcessCsvLine.java:87)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.opencsv.bean.FieldAccess.lambda$determineAssignmentMethod$3(FieldAccess.java:79)
    at com.opencsv.bean.FieldAccess.setField(FieldAccess.java:115)
    at com.opencsv.bean.AbstractBeanField.assignValueToField(AbstractBeanField.java:286)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvValidationException: 'Contact First Name' must be between 3-8 characters long
    at org.lotia.example.entity.Contact.setContactFirstName(Contact.java:23)
    ... 15 more

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvBeanIntrospectionException: An introspection error was thrown while attempting to manipulate property contactFirstName of bean org.lotia.example.entity.Contact.

    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.IntolerantThreadPoolExecutor.checkExceptions(IntolerantThreadPoolExecutor.java:253)
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.LineExecutor.checkExceptions(LineExecutor.java:67)
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.IntolerantThreadPoolExecutor.areMoreResultsAvailable(IntolerantThreadPoolExecutor.java:303)
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.IntolerantThreadPoolExecutor.tryAdvance(IntolerantThreadPoolExecutor.java:313)
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.LineExecutor.tryAdvance(LineExecutor.java:24)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:326)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean.parse(CsvToBean.java:117)
    at org.lotia.example.ContactTest.test(ContactTest.java:28)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvBeanIntrospectionException: An introspection error was thrown while attempting to manipulate property contactFirstName of bean org.lotia.example.entity.Contact.
    at com.opencsv.bean.AbstractBeanField.assignValueToField(AbstractBeanField.java:290)
    at com.opencsv.bean.AbstractBeanField.setFieldValue(AbstractBeanField.java:182)
    at com.opencsv.bean.AbstractMappingStrategy.setFieldValue(AbstractMappingStrategy.java:607)
    at com.opencsv.bean.AbstractMappingStrategy.populateNewBean(AbstractMappingStrategy.java:330)
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.processLine(ProcessCsvLine.java:131)
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.run(ProcessCsvLine.java:87)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.opencsv.bean.FieldAccess.lambda$determineAssignmentMethod$3(FieldAccess.java:79)
    at com.opencsv.bean.FieldAccess.setField(FieldAccess.java:115)
    at com.opencsv.bean.AbstractBeanField.assignValueToField(AbstractBeanField.java:286)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvValidationException: 'Contact First Name' must be between 3-8 characters long
    at org.lotia.example.entity.Contact.setContactFirstName(Contact.java:23)
    ... 15 more


Process finished with exit code 255
```

Comment: There is no option to provide a customized message when using a `PreAssignmentValidator`. You can, however, use any standard validation library (such as [Hibernate Validator](https://hibernate.org/validator/)), to perform _post-conversion_ validation. Hibernate, for example, supports custom parameterized messages.

Comment: @andrewjames Thanks for your suggestion. I am still struggling to see how to get it to work the way I would like it to function. I added some simple validation to the setter and if the validation fails, throw a CsvValidationException. But it's not doing how I had intended. I will update my sample with what I have done. If you are able to post an example, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Are you asking for an example based on your approach (which I am not able to do) or for an example based on Hibernate?

Comment: @andrewjames If the hibernate approach can show how to capture the validation errors during parsing, and then list these out at the end of parsing, that would be really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate's validation is post-conversion - so that means you have to read the data from CSV into the target `Contact` list of beans first.

But you can still capture all the validation messages in a systematic way - and you can customize them to meet your specific needs.

First you need some extra libraries:

- Hibernate validator (and its dependencies)
- Glassfish's EL (expression language) processor

I use Maven for these:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1-b11</version>
</dependency>
```

Now you can remove your `@PreAssignmentValidator` annotations from the `Contact` class and use this new import:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
```

The annotations:

```
@Pattern(regexp="^[A-Za-z]{3,8}$", 
        message="The value '${validatedValue}' in the 'Contact First Name' column did not match the expected format of 3 to 8 letters.")
@CsvBindByName(column = "Contact First Name", required = true)
private String contactFirstName;

@Pattern(regexp="^[0-9]{10}$", message="Another custom message...")
@CsvBindByName(column = "Phone Number", required = true)
private String phone;
```

When processing the CSV file, your logic remains the same as in the original question. But instead of using `beans.getCapturedExceptions()`, you can use Hibernate.

The following imports are needed:

```
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
```

Hibernate provides the implementation classes you need for these.

The main logic (adapted for my test cases):

```
Path csvFilePath = Paths.get("C:/tmp/csv/test_01.csv");
final CsvToBean<Contact> beans = new CsvToBeanBuilder<Contact>(
        Files.newBufferedReader(csvFilePath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
        .withType(Contact.class)
        .withThrowExceptions(false)
        .build();

List<Contact> contacts = beans.parse();

ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

for (Contact contact : contacts) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Contact>> violations = validator.validate(contact);
    for (ConstraintViolation<Contact> violation : violations) {
        System.out.println(violation.getMessage());
    }
}
```

For a CSV input row of this:

```
joe9,123456789
```

You will get the following error message printed:

> The value 'joe9' in the 'Contact First Name' column did not match the expected format of 3 to 8 letters.

To be clear, this is *not* happening during CSV parsing, but as a separate step afterwards. This is (in my experience) typically how Hibernate is used, for basic validation.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to add another library, you can also create a custom validator to use instead of MustMatchRegexExpression:

```
public class MySpecialMustMatchRegexExpression implements StringValidator {
    private String regex = "";


    public MustMatchRegexExpression() {
        this.regex = "";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value) {
        if (regex.isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        }
        return value.matches(regex);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(String value, BeanField field) throws CsvValidationException {
        if (!isValid(value)) {
            throw new CsvValidationException(String.format(ResourceBundle.getBundle("mustMatchRegex", field.getErrorLocale())
                    .getString("validator.regex.mismatch"), field.getDeclaredAnnotations[1], value, regex));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setParameterString(String value) {
        if (value != null && !value.isEmpty()) {
            regex = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And use that in your preassignment validator:

```
@PreAssignmentValidator(validator = MySpecialMustMatchRegexExpression.class, paramString = "^[A-Za-z]{3,8}$")
@CsvBindByName(column = "Contact First Name", required = true)
private String contactFirstName;
```